# Is AngularJS a good choice if I want my website to be also used on phones?

Tags: angularjs

I have to create a small/medium web application which require quite a lot of JavaScript use.

I was planning on using AngularJS mostly because I'm familiar with it.

My question is: How well will my application work on a phone web browser if it's using AngularJS?

Comment: javascript is javascript. Works the same everywhere. It's markup/design you'll likely to have troubles with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using one of the responsive web CSS frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for your HTML you are good to go. There are many great web sites with bootstrap and angularjs that look awesome on mobile devices too.